Kerberos kdc, how to force generation of AES keys on Solaris?
I want to avoid old and weak ciphers on my Solaris kdc, using only AES.
I have edited kdc.conf
   master_key_type = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
   supported_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96:normal aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96:normal

those are lines for krb5.conf
default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96
permitted_encryptes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96 aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96

Restart kdc and kadmin and..
kadmin -p kws/admin -wmypassword
Authenticating as principal kws/admin with password.
kadmin:  

addprinc NFS/debian.myserv.priv@MYSERV.PRIV

ktadd -k nfs.keytab -e aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96  NFS/debian.myserv.priv@MYSERV.PRIV
ktadd: Invalid argument while parsing keysalts aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96

Trying default..
ktadd -k nfs.keytab NFS/debian.myserv.priv@MYSERV.PRIV
Entry for principal NFS/debian.myserv.priv@MYSERV.PRIV with kvno 3, encryption type AES-256 CTS mode with 96-bit SHA-1 HMAC added to keytab WRFILE:nfs.keytab.
Entry for principal NFS/debian.myserv.priv@MYSERV.PRIV with kvno 3, encryption type AES-128 CTS mode with 96-bit SHA-1 HMAC added to keytab WRFILE:nfs.keytab.
Entry for principal NFS/debian.myserv.priv@MYSERV.PRIV with kvno 3, encryption type Triple DES cbc mode with HMAC/sha1 added to keytab WRFILE:nfs.keytab.
Entry for principal NFS/debian.myserv.priv@MYSERV.PRIV with kvno 3, encryption type ArcFour with HMAC/md5 added to keytab WRFILE:nfs.keytab.
Entry for principal NFS/debian.myserv.priv@MYSERV.PRIV with kvno 3, encryption type DES cbc mode with RSA-MD5 added to keytab WRFILE:nfs.keytab.

Why generate the des keys? Is possible to force AES cipher instead?
EDIT: I found a way to create only aes256keys
ktadd -e aes256-cts:normal -k nfs.keytab NFS/debian.myserv.priv@MYSERV.PRIV

The question still stay to found a way to force/generate only aes256 keys.

Why is your NFS/ service type upper-case? Unix Kerberos is case-sensitive, and tools that request a ticket for the standard nfs/ won't be able to find this principal. Only HTTP/ is normally upper-case; all other service types are normally lower-case.

also: do the keytab contents really matter, considering that the KDC is already configured to never issue such tickets?

I don't think about this in effect.

Waiting for a better solution I use this workaround creating keys
ktadd -e aes256-cts:normal -k nfs.keytab NFS/debian.myserv.priv@MYSERV.PRIV

